# Rust rocket file upload endpoint

Tags: rust

I'm currently learning rust and need a rocket file upload enpoint for a project.

This is what i currently have:

It needs to get the file, convert it and add a entry with the file name and timestamp to a database.

```
#[post("/upload?<auth>", data = "<file>")]
pub async fn upload(
                config: &State<Config>,
                db: &State<Db>, 
                mut file: Form<TempFile<'_>>,
                auth: Option<String>
            ) -> Status {

    if !is_valid_token(auth, &config) {
        return Status::Forbidden 
    }

    let filename = utils::get_random_string(20);
    let temp_path = Path::new("/tmp").join(&filename);
    let save_path = Path::new(&config.image_dir).join(&filename); 

    if let Err(_) = file.copy_to(&temp_path).await {
        return Status::InternalServerError
    };

    let image_res = utils::check_and_convert_image(&temp_path, &save_path);
    if let Err(_) = image_res {
        if let Err(_) = fs::remove_file(temp_path) {
            return Status::InternalServerError
        }

        return Status::BadRequest
    }

    if let Err(_) = fs::remove_file(temp_path) {
        return Status::InternalServerError
    }

    let timestamp = SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap().as_secs();
    let db_entry = Entry {
        timestamp,
        filename,
    };

    if let Err(_) = db.create_entry(db_entry) {
        return Status::InternalServerError
    };

    return Status::Ok
}
```

In the rocket docs it says that using Status as a return type is not recommended (https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/responses/#responses) and checking if every function fails seems like bad practise.

Is there a better way of doing this?